# How to edit the auto format in JetBrains Rider?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, format, jetbrains-ide, rider

I'm frequently using auto format in Rider IDE but I don't like some of those formats. I already checked **Editor > Code Style > C#** and searched the internet but couldn't find the desired settings.

For example this what I want when auto format:

[image: Desired format]

But it changes like this when auto format which I don't want:

[image: Unwanted format]

Does anyone have an idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the attributes, you could alter the rule in  `Settings > Editor > Code Style > C# > Line Breaks and Wrapping > Arrangement of Attributes section > Place field attribute on the same line > Never`

---

For a more specific layout, what you're after is the [File Layout](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/File_and_Type_Layout.html), which is located in `Settings > Editor > Code Style > C# > File Layout > General / Unity` which will format your code based on patterns:

[image: Image of the File Layout in Rider]

There are several built-in patterns (Empty, Default, and Default with regions) but you can create your own.

Comment: As you mentioned, I changed settings like 'Settings > Editor > Code Style > C# > Line Breaks and Wrapping > Arrangement of Attributes section > Place field attribute on the same line > Never' and this works fine if there is no [Header] attribute on above. If there is, its separating below [SerializeField] only, other ones OK. Is there a specific way to fix that too?

Comment: In the same properties, there's `Keep existing arrangement of attributes`, which will maintain the custom formatting you're after. Although this also might nullify the purpose of auto-arrangement.